# 3.5mm Stereo to dual 6.3mm mono. Would this work?

Tags: audio, safety, wiring, operational-amplifier

I need to build an adapter which does not seem to be readily available so I can use an audio mixer with my iMac and iPad.

The adapter will convert one 3.5mm male stereo jack to two 6.3mm male mono jacks. One 6.3mm jack will be for the left channel and the other will be for the right.

Would the circuit in the diagram found below work, is it safe, and are there any improvements that could be made?  :

[image: Diagram which converts from the two connector types.]

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Should work, although you can just buy these things: http://www.gear4music.com/G4M/Stereo-Minijack-Mono-Jack-x2-Cable-1m/108R?origin=product-ads&campaign=PLA+Shop+-+GENERIC&adgroup=GENERIC&medium=vertical_search&network=google&merchant_id=1279443&product_id=46971d1&product_country=GB&product_partition_id=121022107759&gclid=COiGkMSQqdICFYm4GwodixkJ0A

Comment: @pjc50 Hah! Didn't see that. I still want to build my own as I have most of the parts lying around. Thanks for the extremely quick response. Please can you post you comment as an answer so I can check this as solved under your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pjc50 Answered in comments:

Should work, although you can just buy these things: [gear4music.com/G4M/Stereo-Minijack-Mono-Jack-x2-Cable-1m/…](http://www.gear4music.com/G4M/Stereo-Minijack-Mono-Jack-x2-Cable-1m/108R?origin=product-ads&campaign=PLA%20Shop%20-%20GENERIC&adgroup=GENERIC&medium=vertical_search&network=google&merchant_id=1279443&product_id=46971d1&product_country=GB&product_partition_id=121022107759&gclid=COiGkMSQqdICFYm4GwodixkJ0A)